# Testing universal link ios

Tags: ios, swift

I am facing a problem where I can't test the universal link on iOS.

If I **download the app** from the store and run it, on pressing the link it redirects to the app correctly,
while running from **Xcode**, and pressing on the link, in the safari top banner, it says view, not open, asking to download the app.

Here is the entitlement
[image]

Capaility
[image]

The AASA file, hosted under /.well-known/apple-app-site-association.
[image]

Comment: I checked the bundle id is the same, is there any way to check if they are different

Comment: Are you running the same scheme in Xcode ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but you have `APS Environment: production`, when testing from XCode I have `APS Environment: development`, everything works well in both cases.

Also make sure you specified `Associated Domains` without `https`, only `domain.com`

If it is not your cases - provide a link please.

Comment: I tried this solution, and still nothing change